# Solving for $x$ in a messy square root equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, numerical-methods

I have these equations:
$$H(t)=h_A+2nh(t)\\
h(t)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac A2-xt\right)^2}\\
(t_2-t_1)v_H=H(t_2)-H(t_1)$$
The problem is that squaring both sides in the last one will give me a product of square roots from which I cannot extract $x$.
Is there any other way of going about this? Maybe an approximation? My goal is $x=f(v_H, t_1, t_2)$.
$$\left(\frac{(t2-t_1)v_H}{2n}\right)^2=2\left(\frac{l}{2}\right)^2-x^2(t_2^2+t_1^2)+xA(t_2+t_1)-2\left(\frac A2\right)^2-2h(t_2)h(t_1)$$
Thank you for your time!

**EDIT:**
Defining $v_H$ as the derivative of $H(t)$ instead works, but the solutions are really, really ugly. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+x+in+%284n%5E2t%5E2%29x%5E4+-+%284n%5E2At%29x%5E3+%2B+%5B%28%28A%2F2%29%5E2%294n%5E2%2Bt%5E2v%5E2%5Dx%5E2+-+%28Atv%5E2%29x+-+v%28l%2F2%29%5E2+%3D+0

Comment: Why can you not just solve the middle equation for x? I don't see why the first and third equations need to come into it.

Comment: @Paul because i want it as a function of $v_H,\,t_1$ and $t_2$.

Comment: Just follow Paul's advice, you will get what you want.

Comment: They are so many symbols $H, h, t, A, h_A, x, l, t_1,t_2, v_H,n$ that it is very difficult to make the difference between the variables, the constants, what is known, what is unknown. More explanations would just make thinks even more confuse. So I suggest that you add in your question one representative example of numerical data and what do you exepect to be derived from this data.

Comment: One has to solve 
$$
\frac{v_H}{n}=\frac{h(t_2)-h(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}
=\frac{\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_2)^2}-\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_1)^2}}{t_2-t_1}
=\frac{x(2A-x(t_1+t_2))}{\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_2)^2}+\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_1)^2}}
$$
for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Squaring the equation

$$
\frac{v_H(t_2-t_1)}{2n}=\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_2)^2}-\sqrt{l^2-(A-xt_1)^2}\tag1
$$
one obtains:
$$
\left[\frac{v_H(t_2-t_1)}{2n}\right]^2-2l^2+(A-xt_2)^2+(A-xt_1)^2=-2\sqrt{\Big[l^2-(A-xt_2)^2\Big]\Big[l^2-(A-xt_1)^2\Big]}
$$
which implies:

$$\left[\left[\frac{v_H(t_2-t_1)}{2n}\right]^2-2l^2+(A-xt_2)^2+(A-xt_1)^2\right]^2=4\Big[l^2-(A-xt_2)^2\Big]\Big[l^2-(A-xt_1)^2\Big].\tag2
$$

This is a polynomial equation of $4$-th order in $x$. It can be solved in radicals but the solution looks quite ugly, so I will not give it here.